# Swiper.io starts at last slide depending on where the data is set

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I am using https://swiperjs.com/ and working with Vue framework. I will explain the different scenarios:

Scenario 1 (produces bug, need a fix for this):
I am getting reviews from a GraphQL query. The answer is used to populate the swiper. This way of dynamically adding the content to the swiper gives me a bug where the slider starts at the last slide.

Scenario 2(works, but the content is manually set): I have a defined the content of reviews as a variable in my data section. Slider works as it should. Setting the data manually in all lifecycles except beforeCreate works with no bugs.

This is my the relevant code:

```
  getProductReviews(this.$apollo, { sku: 0 })
    .then(result => {
      // const temp = result.data.getBVReviews.reviews;
      // result.data.getBVReviews.reviews.push(temp[0]);
      // result.data.getBVReviews.reviews.push(temp[1]);
      this.getBVReviews = result.data.getBVReviews;
      if (this.isMounted) {
        this.setupReviewSlider();
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Failed to load review data.');
      console.log(error);
    });

setupReviewSlider() {
      this.reviewSlider = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        slidesPerView: 'auto',
        initialSlide: 0,
        observer: true,
        observParents: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });
      // this.reviewSlider.on('reachEnd', () => {
      //   this.reviewSlider.slideTo(0, false,false);
      //   this.reviewSlider.autoplay = false;
      // })
    },
```

The HTML part is pretty big and it would only confuse you. I doubt that there is a need to see it but if you do just tell me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the slides in the correct order in outputted HTML? Also btw you have a typo in `observParents`

Comment: Yes they are in the correct order @BrettGregson